# Google Cloud IoT core upload images

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iot

The maximum payload size with IoT Core is 256kb and as such I can't use the HTTP Connection to upload photos from my raspberry pi.

Is there any way I can use IoT Core to authorize my device to upload to GCS directly / utilize other GCP services?

Comment: I think you might find these other posts [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50774544/how-can-an-iot-device-upload-a-file-to-the-cloud) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64124392/how-to-send-images-from-esp32-cam-to-iot-core) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59951444/why-cant-i-send-image-to-google-cloud-iot-core-with-mqtt-using-python-with-thi) to be useful. Do you face any particular issues with the raspberry pi in order not to implement any of the methods explained within the shared posts?

Comment: I'm surprised I didn't see the first 2 posts in my research. Thanks for this!

Comment: I'm very glad that those links solve your doubts!